# Single line simple mq4 documented function not working

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

The following simple script is producing no output:

```
void OnStart()
  {
   Print(SymbolName(1, false));
  }
```

The log file entries are as follows:

```
2   11:35:32.112    Script scratch USDCHF,M1: loaded successfully
2   11:35:34.147    Script scratch USDCHF,M1: removed
```

The marketwatch is as per the screenshot:

[image: MarketWatch Screenshot]

what am I missing??

Comment: what did u mean with output? a Popout Msg on the screen and Alert? Print will only join the logfiles

Comment: I mean an entry in the logfile - I am debugging a larger script but as per the logfile reproduced above, there is no statement produced. I was expecting ```11:35:xx.xxx    Script scratch USDCHF,M1: USDCHF```